# angular 2 new router: Back- and Forward-Button of Browser not working correctly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

http://plnkr.co/edit/UHeuW7QIFhHnHVT8itoj?p=preview

this is a plunkr provided by google to demo relative navigation:

```
export class CrisisListComponent implements OnActivate {
  crises: Crisis[];
  private currSegment: RouteSegment;
  private selectedId: number;

  constructor(
    private service: CrisisService,
    private router: Router) { }

  isSelected(crisis: Crisis) { return crisis.id === this.selectedId; }

  routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment, prev: RouteSegment, currTree: RouteTree) {
    this.currSegment = curr;
    this.selectedId = +currTree.parent(curr).getParam('id');
    this.service.getCrises().then(crises => this.crises = crises);
  }

  onSelect(crisis: Crisis) {
    // Absolute link
    // this.router.navigate([`/crisis-center`, crisis.id]);

    // Relative link
    this.router.navigate([`./${crisis.id}`], this.currSegment);
  }
}
```

Now in my version of Chrome the Browsers Forward-Button will not work correctly after I clicked on the Back-Button.

Reproduce error:

- click on one of the items in the list
- click the back-button
- --> now the forward-button is disabled

expected: forward-button to be enabled and leading to the detailed view of the clicked item

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to download this project and run in your localhost?

Comment: I have a similar project on my server and the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue with `@angular/router` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9088

This router will again be replaced. The new new router is work in progress but will probably be made available soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when using server-rendered content this navigation would re-request content from the server or could re-display cached content. With a client-side framework this navigation has to be simulated because the navigation doesn’t actually happen and the state history is stored and passed to the app instead for the same effect.

Source : http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/04/02/angular2-new-component-router-review/